# Where come from this header date in response? (spring-saml2 with Tomcat)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-saml

I'm using spring-security-saml2 api to establish connections.

It worked well for a while but lately I experienced some troubles with a date in a response header.
When the filter `org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter` is called (url -> `/saml/SSO/alias/defaultAlias`), the response contains a header `date` and this date is **SOMETIMES** 2 hours late.

Hence I get an error `Etat HTTP 401 - Authentication Failed : Response issue time is either too old or with date in the future, skew 60, time 2014-10-22T08:25:55.967Z` (tested at 10h25)

I've not any idea how the date is retrieved and why this behaviour only happens periodically.
I'm looking for any clue. Thanks.

Comment: If it happens only sometimes, maybe only one server in your farm has the wrong timezone set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What time-zone are you in? The *2014-10-22T08:25:55.967Z* is in UTC, so the 2 hour difference between your local time could be explained by being in GMT+2 (e.g. France summer time).

My guess is that the clock between your IDP and SP is not correctly synchronized, and sometimes the time difference between creation of the Response object (*2014-10-22T08:25:55.967Z*) and time on your SP machine goes above 60 seconds.

Try changing your `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl` bean and declare it as follows, it's likely to solve your problem:

```
<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl">
    <property name="responseSkew" value="180"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir. Thank you for the answer! Yes you're right I'm in GMT+2 so it explains the 2 hours late. I'll try to increase the skew value. I let you know if it solve it on Monday ;)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I forgot to give you a feedback but yes increasing the response skew made it worked!